# Invalid data binding expression when running AzureML pipeline

Tags: python, azure-ml-pipelines

I'm running an AzureML pipeline using the command line where the sole job (for now) is a sweep.

When I run
`run_id=$(az ml job create -f path_to_pipeline/pipeline.yaml --query name -o tsv -g grp_name -w ws-name)`,
I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Met error <class 'Exception'>:{
  "result": "Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Invalid data binding expression: inputs.data, outputs.model_output, search_space.batch_size, search_space.learning_rate",
      "path": "command",
      "value": "python train.py --data_path ${{inputs.data}} --output_path ${{outputs.model_output}} --batch_size ${{search_space.batch_size}} --learning_rate ${{search_space.learning_rate}}"
    }
  ]
}
```

The pipeline yaml looks like this:

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/pipelineJob.schema.json
type: pipeline
display_name: pipeline_with_hyperparameter_sweep
description: Tune hyperparameters
settings:
  default_compute: azureml:compute-name  # sub with your compute name
jobs:
  sweep_step:
    type: sweep
    inputs:
      data:
        type: uri_file
        path: azureml:code_train_data:1  #data store I created
    outputs:
      model_output:
    sampling_algorithm: random
    search_space:
      batch_size:
        type: choice
        values: [1, 5, 10, 15]
      learning_rate:
        type: loguniform
        min_value: -6.90775527898 # ln(0.001)
        max_value: -2.30258509299 # ln(0.1)
    trial:
      code: ../src
      command: >-
        python train.py 
        --data_path ${{inputs.data}} 
        --output_path ${{outputs.model_output}} 
        --batch_size ${{search_space.batch_size}} 
        --learning_rate ${{search_space.learning_rate}}
      environment: azureml:env_finetune_component:1
    objective:
      goal: maximize
      primary_metric: bleu_score
    limits:
      max_total_trials: 5
      max_concurrent_trials: 3
      timeout: 3600
      trial_timeout: 720
```

For the `train.py` file, note that I of course have a lot of actual code in in the main function, but I commented it out with pass to check if it makes a difference and the error is the same.  So the problem is upstream with the bindings, not what's inside of train.

```py
import argparse

def main(args):
    pass

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_arguments("--data_path")
    parser.add_arguments("--output_path")
    parser.add_arguments("--batch_size", type=int)
    parser.add_arguments("--learning_rate", type=float)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


if __name__ == "__main__":

    args = parse_args()

    main(args)
```

If helpful, here's output when I run `az version`:

```
{
  "azure-cli": "2.53.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.53.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.1.0",
  "extensions": {
    "ml": "2.20.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  The `pipeline.yaml` syntax for trial is in fact just
`trial: filename.yaml`:

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/pipelineJob.schema.json
type: pipeline
display_name: codegen_sweep
description: Tune hyperparameters
settings:
  default_compute: azureml:roma2
jobs:
  sweep_step:
    type: sweep
    inputs:
      data_path:
        type: uri_file
        path: azureml:code_train_data:1
    outputs:
      model_output:
    sampling_algorithm: random
    search_space:
      batch_size:
        type: choice
        values: [1, 5, 10, 15]
      learning_rate:
        type: loguniform
        min_value: -6.90775527898 # ln(0.001)
        max_value: -2.30258509299 # ln(0.1)
    trial: ./train.yaml
    objective:
      goal: maximize
      primary_metric: eval_bleu_score # how mlflow outputs in other models
    limits:
      max_total_trials: 5
      max_concurrent_trials: 3
      timeout: 3600 # 1 hour
      trial_timeout: 720 # 20 mins
```

There was another problem.  In the `train.yaml` file, my source directory is parallel, so I needed to specify using `../src`:

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/commandComponent.schema.json
type: command

name: train_model
display_name: train_model
version: 1

inputs:
  data_path:
    type: uri_file
  batch_size:
    type: integer
  learning_rate:
    type: number

outputs:
  model_output:
    type: mlflow_model

code: ../src

environment: azureml:AzureML-sklearn-1.0-ubuntu20.04-py38-cpu@latest

command: >-
  python train.py
    --data_path ${{inputs.data_path}}
    --output_path ${{outputs.model_output}}
    --batch_size ${{inputs.batch_size}}
    --learning_rate ${{inputs.learning_rate}}
```

Note I simplified the arguments just to focus on getting this to work.  Additionally, I fixed the `parser.add_arguments` as per one of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Invalid data binding expression", typically indicates an issue with how the inputs and outputs are specified in your AzureML pipeline YAML file.

Looking at your YAML file, everything seems to be structured correctly. However, there's one small mistake in the outputs section of the sweep_step job. It's missing the type property.

Here's the corrected section:

```
outputs:
  model_output:
    type: azureml:artifact
```

Make sure to add the type property with the value azureml:artifact as shown above. This specifies that model_output is an output artifact.

If you still encounter the error after making this change, double-check all your references and paths in the pipeline YAML file. Ensure that the inputs and outputs are correctly defined and referenced throughout the file.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  I don't think that's it.  Adding as per your suggestion results in :
ValidationError: Validation for PipelineJobSchema failed:
 "message": "Not a valid string.; Invalid output binding string '{'type': 'azureml:artifact'}' passed; {'type': [\"Value 'azureml:artifact' passed is not in set ['uri_file', 'uri_folder', 'custom_model', 'mlflow_model', 'mltable', 'triton_model']\"]}.  If I substitute azureml_artifact with mlflow_model, I get the same error as in my original post.